# Mostrar COUNT del numero de registros coincidentes en un campo de la misma tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla llamada **articulos**, entre otros campos como **codigo**, **descripcion** etc...
Esta tiene dos campos llamados **PadreHijo** y **CodigoPadre**.
Si un registro tiene el valor '**H**' en el campo **padreHijo**, nos indica que este tiene un producto padre, el cual indicamos en el **codigoPadre**.
Me gustaría hacer una consulta que me retornara los productos padre con el número de hijos que tiene cada uno.
Lo he intentado con un `SELF JOIN`, pero no hay manera.
¿Alguien me puede echar una mano?
Gracias.

EDIT:
Disculpar, el código no funcionaba y por eso no lo había pegado aquí, pero es que había probado con una subconsulta en el select y con un self join i no funcionaba ni de lejos.
Este es el código con el que lo que estaba intentando y no me funciobaba porque estaba ofuscado perdón.

```
select A.CodigoArticulo, Count(B.CodigoPadre)
from Articulos as A Join Articulos as B 
On a.CodigoArticulo = b.CodigoPadre
Group bY A.CodigoArticulo,A.padrehijo
```

Comment: Las preguntas de ¿Cómo hago esto? no son bien recibidas, te invito a compartir tu código y progreso para mejor aceptación.

Comment: Podrias mostrarnos como lo intentaste????

Comment: He editado mi pregunta, disculpar, pero me daba reparo pegar el código por que ni siquiera sabía si lo estaba enfocando correctamente.Perdon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay una solucion mucho mas simple de la planteada:

si CodigoPadre tiene efectivamente los codigos de los padres, podes contar esos solamente de la siguiente forma:

```
select codigopadre, count(*) 
from articulos 
group by codigopadre
```

Si queres que los null no los cuente, agrega un where a ese query para que no los cuente..

Si ademas, queres la descripcion del padre, podes usar este query como ingreso de otra, donde busques la descripción.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que algo así puede servirte.
Te invito a que la proxima vez escribas algo de código y pidas ayuda desde los errores que se te presentan.

```
Select Count(p.Codigo) N_Hijos, p.Codigo, p.Descripcion from Articulos p
inner join (
    select CodigoPadre from Articulo t
    where CodigoPadre <> '' AND CodigoPadre is Not Null
) pt on pt.CodigoPadre = p.Codigo
Group By p.Codigo, p.Descripcion
```

Comment: mas alla que estaria bueno saber que intento, la solucion es muchisimo mas simple.. si el campo codigopadre tiene el codigo efectivo del padre, alcanza con hacer un select codigopadre, count(*) from articulos group by codigopadre... con eso solo, te va a traer la cantidad de hijos para cada padre...

Comment: @gbianchi de acuerdo contigo.